# Need help understanding this issue regarding relative vs absolute imports in Python

Tags: python, import, python-import

I was getting an error when I wanted to install a certain Python package in a specific folder (using pip install -t), and then import a module from that package.

I posted the issue on the package's Github and it turns out I can't install a package in a certain folder; that it isn't supported for the package to be installed that way.

> Even without google collab, I can reproduce the import error when trying to install sklearn in some specific folder with pip install -t sklearnFolder then importing it as sklearnFolder.sklearn.manifold.
>
> That is not a supported way of installing / using scikit-lean. One reason why it wouldn't work is that a few modules in scikit-learn use absolute imports (e.g. from sklearn import something) which will fail with such setup.
>
> You should either install it with pip install  or if you want to have it in some specific folder, clone the repo to that folder, then run pip install -e , in both cases it will be imported as sklearn.

From https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11656

I don't quite get the explanation.

I thought something like

```
from folderName.package import module
```

is the same as

```
from package import module
```

Because they're both absolute imports. As in, they both completely specify the path of the imported module. So there is something off about my understanding but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an import you do not specify the folderName to prefix a package. If the package is installed or in the python path, then you just use the package name to import.

```
    # Assume the below structure is under a directory (folder) called /app/home/packages.

    reservation/                  This is your top-level pacakge 
        __init__.py               Initialize the package
        hotels/                   Subpackage for hotel reservations
            __init__.py
            slots.py
            bid.py
            demand.py
            ...
            restaurents/                  Another Subpackage under hotels 
                __init__.py
                cuisine.py
                hours.py
                tableslots.py
                ...
        rewards/                      Subpackage for rewards
            __init__.py
            points.py
            discounts.py
            membersonly.py
            ...
```

As the package is under /app/home/packages, then the following import is NOT valid as you prefix the folder name.

```
    from packages.reservation import hotels
```

The correct way to import is from the actual package which has the package initialization __init__.py. If you see in the example, reservation folder has __init__.py.

```
    from reservation import hotels
```

If you want to import the sub module under the hotels, then you will prefix with the package:

```
   from reservation.hotels import restaurents
```

Alternatively you can import directly the sub module but you will have to prefix with the package when you use it:

```
   import reservation.hotels.restaurents
```

Comment: What if the package was in a different folder, not in the python path ?

Comment: If it is in non-python location, then you will have to append the path.  
`import sys
sys.path.append('/app/home/others')
from myscript import x,y,z`